# Is it possible to show multiple graph base in input control in jasperstudio

Tags: jasper-reports

In jasperstudio i am using HTML5 charts to make graph...but i want it to show multiple graph base on the selection in the input control for example

1. Select A then graph only show A
2. Select A and B graph will show A and B data in 2 graph
3. Select A, B, C will show 3 graphs A, B, and C

How to do it? and when the chart appear it will resize itself in equal proportion based on the report size

Comment: No i don't want to hide i want them to show based on data i selected on the input parameter

Comment: my apology I think you must have misunderstood.. SELECT A show 1 Graph A and if you SELECT A and B it will show 2 graph A and B graph as stated in point 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Yes thats how i want it